# Doctrine Query Giving Unexpected Results Within ZF2 Service

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am receiving unexpected results from the Doctrine query below.  I am unsure of the reason why.

This is the query I am trying to create:

```
SELECT `subscription_reference` 
FROM `member_subscriptions` 
WHERE `list` = 1 AND `quantity` = 1 
    AND `payment_received` = 1 AND `email` = 'user@domain.com' 
    AND `subscription_consent_date` != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
    AND ( ( `subscription_expires` = '0000-00-00' ) 
         OR ( '2015-01-22' <= `subscription_expires` ) )
```

These are the commands I used I assemble the query:

```
$query1 = $this->entityManager
               ->createQueryBuilder()
               ->select('s.subscriptionReference')
               ->from('AMDatabase\Entity\Membership\MemberSubscriptions', 's');

$query1->andWhere($query1->expr()->eq('s.list', ':list'))
       ->setParameter('list', 1);

$query1->andWhere($query1->expr()->eq('s.quantity', ':quantity'))
       ->setParameter('quantity', 1);

$query1->andWhere($query1->expr()->eq('s.paymentReceived', ':paymentReceived'))
       ->setParameter('paymentReceived', 1);

$query1->andWhere($query1->expr()->eq('s.email', ':email'))
       ->setParameter('email', $params['email_address']);

$query1->andWhere($query1->expr()->notLike('s.subscriptionConsentDate', ':subscriptionConsentDate'))
       ->setParameter('subscriptionConsentDate', new \DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00'));

$query1->orWhere($query1->expr()->eq('s.subscriptionExpires', ':subscriptionExpires1'))
       ->setParameter('subscriptionExpires1', '0000-00-00');

$query1->orWhere($query1->expr()->lt('s.subscriptionExpires', ':subscriptionExpires2'))
       ->setParameter('subscriptionExpires2', gmdate('Y-m-d'));

$result1 = $query1->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

if (is_array($result1) && count($result1) > '0') {
    foreach ($result1 AS $value1) {
        print_r( $value1 );
    }
 }
```

This is an example result the Doctrine query produces:

```
subscription_reference 38
member_reference 6
list 1
quantity 1  
payment_received 1
email user@domain.com
subscription_consent_reference  0
subscription_consent_date 0000-00-00 00:00:00
subscription_consent_ip_address 
subscription_consent_granted_name   
subscription_begins 2005-11-05
subscription_expires 2014-06-30
email_delivery_hour 0
email_delivery_timezone_reference 241
last_mailing 2014-06-30
administrator_update_reference 0
administrator_update_timestamp 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

The unexpected results are:

1. subscription_consent_date having a value of '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

   - I need it to have an actual date, such as '2005-11-05 11:30:34'
2. subscription_expires having a value of '2014-06-30'

   - I need this date to be either in the future or '0000-00-00' (meaning the subscription is ongoing)
3. multiple subscription_reference

   - Multiple subscriptions are being selected, instead of the one I have tried to describe.  I was expecting the e-mail address given in the query to isolate from all other subscribers.

Would someone show me how to correct the mistakes I have made?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 possibilities for s.subscriptionExpires need to be within the same "andWhere"

```
                $query1 = $this->entityManager
                    ->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('s.subscriptionReference')
                    ->from(
                        'AMDatabase\Entity\Membership\MemberSubscriptions',
                        's'
                    );

                $query1
                    ->andWhere(
                        $query1->expr()
                              ->eq(
                                  's.list',
                                  ':list'
                              )
                    )
                    ->setParameter(
                        'list',
                        1
                    );

                $query1
                    ->andWhere(
                        $query1->expr()
                               ->eq(
                                   's.quantity',
                                   ':quantity'
                               )
                    )
                    ->setParameter(
                        'quantity',
                        1
                    );

                $query1
                    ->andWhere(
                        $query1->expr()
                               ->eq(
                                   's.paymentReceived',
                                   ':paymentReceived'
                               )
                    )
                    ->setParameter(
                        'paymentReceived',
                        1
                    );

                $query1
                    ->andWhere(
                        $query1->expr()
                               ->eq(
                                   's.email',
                                   ':email'
                               )
                    )
                    ->setParameter(
                        'email',
                        $params['email_address']
                    );

                $query1
                    ->andWhere(
                        $query1->expr()
                               ->notLike(
                                   's.subscriptionConsentDate',
                                   ':subscriptionConsentDate'
                               )
                    )
                    ->setParameter(
                        'subscriptionConsentDate',
                        new \DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                    );

                $query1
                    ->andWhere('s.subscriptionExpires = :subscriptionExpires1 OR s.subscriptionExpires >= :subscriptionExpires2')
                    ->setParameter(
                        'subscriptionExpires1',
                        '0000-00-00'
                    )
                    ->setParameter(
                        'subscriptionExpires2',
                        gmdate('Y-m-d')
                    );

                $result1 = $query1->getQuery()
                                ->getArrayResult();
```

I was given the following code to see the query being created to trouble shoot what was wrong:

```
$q = $query1->getQuery();
$sql = $q->getSQL();
print_r( $sql );
```